# why pattern/matcher find one match twice

Tags: java, regex

I want to find < a > tags in a StringBuilder (result) and insert a word (INSERTED-WORD/) before their href attribute.

code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a [a-zA-Z0-9=\":.;\\s&%_#/\\\\()\\-']*href=['\"]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(result);
while (matcher.find()) {
 int index2 = result.indexOf(matcher.group(0))+ matcher.group(0).length();
 result.insert(index2, "INSERTED-WORD/");
}
```

But some of tags are found twice (or more) and INSERTED-WORD/ is inserted before their href attribute twice or more.

for example,I want to find this tag :

> < a class="link" href="www.example.com">link< /a>

and then change it to

> < a class="link" href="INSERTED-WORD/www.example.com">link< /a>

.
but this code changes it to

> < a class="link"
>   href="INSERTED-WORD/INSERTED-WORD/INSERTED-WORD/www.example.com">link<
>   /a>

How can I fix it?

Comment: what is the input?

Comment: `result.indexOf(matcher.group(0))` It looks like the string is always inserted into the first occurence of the `<a ... href="` and I guess you have 3 occurences of `<a ... href="` there.

Comment: Parsing HTML using regex is error prone. If you must do that then use: `str = str.replaceAll("<a [^>]*?href=\"(?!INSERTED-WORD/)", "$0INSERTED-WORD/");`

Comment: Add negative lookahead `(?!INSERTED-WORD)` to end of your patter: to exclude the inserting into already processed URLs: `Pattern.compile("<a [a-zA-Z0-9=\":.;\\s&%_#/\\\\()\\-']*href=['\"](?!INSERTED-WORD)")`;

Comment: why not you use XML API, it would be very simple?

Comment: another way that I wanted to test is jsoup. But now I decide to use regex. @Simo

Comment: your solution returns true result. @anubhava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you see is caused by the use of `indexOf`. When something is found more than once `indexOf` will search for the same matched string and always return the index of the first match.

This is not the only problem with your code. You also modify `result` while it is used by `matcher`, java's `Matcher` was not designed to deal with that and will not work correctly. An obvious problem is that it will think `result` is shorter than it actually is and there might be other problems.

The following will fix your code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a [a-zA-Z0-9=\":.;\\s&%_#/\\\\()\\-']*href=['\"]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(result.toString()); // Create new String instead of using result
int found = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    int index2 = matcher.end();
    result.insert(index2 + found++ * "INSERTED-WORD/".length(), "INSERTED-WORD/");
}
```

I will leave it to you to figure out why `found` is required, run the code without it and see what happens.

#### Notes

- This is not a good way to solve your problem anubhava offered a much simpler solution in his comment: `result = new StringBuilder(result.toString().replaceAll("<a [^>]*?href=\"(?!INSERTED-WORD/)", "$0INSERTED-WORD/"));`
- The recommended way to parse html is with an html parser https://jsoup.org/ is a good one.

Comment: your code doesn't work correctly. But I will use jsoup. Thanks

Comment: @AtefehRashidi It depends on your input and your regex. It most certainly works on the example you provided. Good you decided to use jsoup.